# RMySQL and data.frame: NAs introduced by coercion to integer range

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I am pulling out data from a MySQL database. The data has float structure in MySQL, but I receive the following error when loading them into data frames: "NAs introduced by coercion to integer range"

Here is the MySQL function:

```
##
## MySQL function
##
library(RMySQL)
rozDB <- function(q,type) {
  mysql_conn <- dbConnect(
    MySQL(), 
    user="", 
    password="", 
    dbname="", 
    host="")

  if(type == "select") {
    query <- dbSendQuery(mysql_conn, q)
    result <- fetch(query, n = Inf)
    check <- dbHasCompleted(query)
  }

  if(type == "insert") {
    query <- dbSendQuery(mysql_conn, q)
    result <- "Complete"
  }

  dbClearResult(query)
  dbDisconnect(mysql_conn)

  return(result)
}
```

and the data call:

```
###
### Build condition map and number of sessions
###

conditions <- c()
query1 <- paste0("SELECT notebook_condition conditions, COUNT(notebook_condition) count FROM key_map GROUP BY notebook_condition;")
conditions <- rozDB(query1, "select")


### 
### Get 1 day of 1 condition
###

selectedCondition <- conditions[3,]

for(i in 1:selectedCondition[1,2]){
  query3 <- paste0("SELECT kx,ky,kz FROM dataread3 WHERE `datetime` BETWEEN (SELECT `start_time` FROM key_map WHERE `cond` = '",selectedCondition[1,1],"' LIMIT ",i,",1) AND (SELECT `end_time` FROM key_map WHERE `cond` = '",selectedCondition[1,1],"' LIMIT ",i,",1);")
  print(query3)
  data <- rozDB(query3,"select")
}
```

Comment: What is `rozDB`?  I have never seen this before.  Also, why are you trying to run three `SELECT` queries in one statement, in your `query3` ?

Comment: (@TimBiegeleisen, `roxDB` is defined in the first code block.) Levi, fyi you generally do not need to `library(RMySQL)`, loading `library(DBI)` and a one-time call to `RMySQL::MySQL()` (in `dbConnect`) is all you need. I've seen interaction with other DBMSs where the DB uses 64-bit integers, but the default in R (sans `bit64`) does not support them ... is it possible there's an option in `RMySQL` to turn them into float or something else? What version of `DBI` are you using?

Comment: Another comment: The subqueries in the `BETWEEN` clause are not well defined, because they are using `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` clause.  We can probably rewrite it.  But, this make not solve your current problem.